# Passing variable in php file before executing in JSON_DATA_URL android studio

Tags: php, android

I,m a beginner in android studio. I know this simple for you guys.
I don't know how to pass `variable($recipe_id)` in my .php file to select only the specific ingredients in a recipe before executing the JSON_DATA_URL.

I'm displaying the ingredients in a listview.

Everything is working fine when I put just an exact number in my .php (no variable)

ex. (`$sql="select * from ingredients where recipe_id =5";`)

thanks in advance :)

This are my codes:

**Activity**

```
    package com.example.x;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.androidnetworking.AndroidNetworking;
import com.androidnetworking.common.Priority;
import com.androidnetworking.error.ANError;
import com.androidnetworking.interfaces.JSONArrayRequestListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Recipe extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout drawer;

    public class Ingredient {
        /*INSTANCE FIELDS*/
        private int i_id;
        private int recipe_id;
        private String i_name;
        private String unit_of_measure;
        private int amount_required;

        /*GETTERS AND SETTERS*/

        public int getI_id() {
            return i_id;
        }

        public void setI_id(int i_id) {
            this.i_id = i_id;
        }

        public int getRecipe_id() {
            return recipe_id;
        }

        public void setRecipe_id(int recipe_id) {
            this.recipe_id = recipe_id;
        }

        public String getI_name() {
            return i_name;
        }

        public void setI_name(String i_name) {
            this.i_name = i_name;
        }

        public String getUnit_of_measure() {
            return unit_of_measure;
        }

        public void setUnit_of_measure(String unit_of_measure) {
            this.unit_of_measure = unit_of_measure;
        }

        public int getAmount_required() {
            return amount_required;
        }

        public void setAmount_required(int amount_required) {
            this.amount_required = amount_required;
        }

        /* TOSTRING         */
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return i_name;
        }
    }

    class FilterHelper extends Filter {
        ArrayList<Ingredient> currentList;
        ListViewAdapter adapter;
        Context c;

        public FilterHelper(ArrayList<Ingredient> currentList, ListViewAdapter adapter, Context c) {
            this.currentList = currentList;
            this.adapter = adapter;
            this.c = c;
        }

        /*
        - Perform actual filtering.
         */
        @Override
        protected Filter.FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            Filter.FilterResults filterResults = new Filter.FilterResults();

            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                //CHANGE TO UPPER
                constraint = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();

                //HOLD FILTERS WE FIND
                ArrayList<Ingredient> foundFilters = new ArrayList<>();

                Ingredient spacecraft = null;

                //ITERATE CURRENT LIST
                for (int i = 0; i < currentList.size(); i++) {
                    spacecraft = currentList.get(i);

                    //SEARCH
                    if (spacecraft.getI_name().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)) {
                        //ADD IF FOUND
                        foundFilters.add(spacecraft);
                    }
                }

                //SET RESULTS TO FILTER LIST
                filterResults.count = foundFilters.size();
                filterResults.values = foundFilters;
            } else {
                //NO ITEM FOUND.LIST REMAINS INTACT
                filterResults.count = currentList.size();
                filterResults.values = currentList;
            }

            //RETURN RESULTS
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, Filter.FilterResults filterResults) {
            adapter.setIngredients((ArrayList<Ingredient>) filterResults.values);
            adapter.refresh();
        }
    }

    /*
    Our custom adapter class
     */
    public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

        Context c;
        ArrayList<Ingredient> spacecrafts;
        public ArrayList<Ingredient> currentList;
        FilterHelper filterHelper;

        public ListViewAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Ingredient> spacecrafts) {
            this.c = c;
            this.spacecrafts = spacecrafts;
            this.currentList = spacecrafts;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return spacecrafts.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return spacecrafts.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            if (view == null) {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.ingredient_model, viewGroup, false);
            }

            TextView i_namex = view.findViewById(R.id.i_name);
            TextView unit_of_measurex = view.findViewById(R.id.unit_of_measure);
            TextView amount_requiredx = view.findViewById(R.id.amount_required);

            final Ingredient s = (Ingredient) this.getItem(i);

            i_namex.setText(s.getI_name());
            unit_of_measurex.setText(s.getUnit_of_measure());
            amount_requiredx.setText(String.valueOf(s.getAmount_required()));
            //----
            final int i_id = (s.getI_id());
            final int recipe_id = (s.getRecipe_id());
            final int amount_required = (s.getAmount_required());
            final String i_name = (s.getI_name());
            final String unit_of_measure = (s.getUnit_of_measure());


            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
//                Intent intent = new Intent(Home3.this, com.example.a05.Recipe.class);
//                intent.putExtra("calorie_per_serving",String.valueOf(calorie_per_serving));
//                intent.putExtra("number_of_serving",number_of_serving);
//                intent.putExtra("recipe_category",recipe_category);
//                intent.putExtra("recipe_desc",recipe_desc);
//                intent.putExtra("preparation_time",preparation_time);
//                intent.putExtra("recipe_instructions",recipe_instructions);
//                intent.putExtra("id",String.valueOf(id));
//                intent.putExtra("name",name);
//                intent.putExtra("propellant",propellant);
//                intent.putExtra("imageURL",imageURL);
//                startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            return view;
        }
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        public void setIngredients(ArrayList<Ingredient> filteredIngredients) {
            this.spacecrafts = filteredIngredients;

        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            if (filterHelper == null) {
                filterHelper = new FilterHelper(currentList, this, c);
            }

            return filterHelper;
        }

        public void refresh() {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    /*
    Our HTTP Client
     */
    public class JSONDownloader {


        //SAVE/RETRIEVE URLS
        private static final String JSON_DATA_URL = "http://abcabc.com/select_ingredients.php";
        //INSTANCE FIELDS
        private final Context c;

        public JSONDownloader(Context c) {
            this.c = c;
        }

        /*
        Fetch JSON Data
         */
        public ArrayList<Ingredient> retrieve(final ListView mListView, final ProgressBar myProgressBar) {
            final ArrayList<Ingredient> downloadedData = new ArrayList<>();
            myProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            AndroidNetworking.get(JSON_DATA_URL)
                    .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
                    .build()
                    .getAsJSONArray(new JSONArrayRequestListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            JSONObject jo;
                            Ingredient s;
                            try {
                                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                    jo = response.getJSONObject(i);

                                    int i_id = jo.getInt("i_id");
                                    int recipe_id = jo.getInt("recipe_id");
                                    int amount_required = jo.getInt("amount_required");
                                    String i_name = jo.getString("i_name");
                                    String unit_of_measure = jo.getString("unit_of_measure");

                                    s = new Ingredient();
                                    s.setI_id(i_id);
                                    s.setRecipe_id(recipe_id);
                                    s.setAmount_required(amount_required);
                                    s.setI_name(i_name);
                                    s.setUnit_of_measure(unit_of_measure);
                                    downloadedData.add(s);
                                }
                                myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                Toast.makeText(c, "GOOD RESPONSE BUT JAVA CAN'T PARSE JSON IT RECEIEVED. " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }

                        //ERROR
                        @Override
                        public void onError(ANError anError) {
                            anError.printStackTrace();
                            myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(c, "UNSUCCESSFUL :  ERROR IS : " + anError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
            return downloadedData;
        }
    }

    ArrayList<Ingredient> spacecrafts = new ArrayList<>();
    ListView myListView;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe);
        final TextView tv_recipe_name = findViewById(R.id.tv_recipe_name);
        final TextView tv_recipe_propellant = findViewById(R.id.tv_recipe_propellant);
        final TextView tv_recipe_instructions = findViewById(R.id.tv_recipe_instructions);
        final ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.iv);

        myListView = findViewById(R.id.myListView);//

        final ProgressBar myProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.myProgressBar);//


        spacecrafts = new JSONDownloader(Recipe.this).retrieve(myListView, myProgressBar);
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, spacecrafts);
        myListView.setAdapter(adapter);

//
//        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
////        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
//        mediaC = new MediaController(this);
//    }
//    public void videoplay(View v){
//        String videopath="https://abcabc.com/files/2.mp4";
//        Uri uri = Uri.parse(videopath);
//        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
//        videoView.setMediaController(mediaC);
//        mediaC.setAnchorView(videoView);
//        videoView.start();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String calorie_per_serving = intent.getStringExtra("calorie_per_serving");
        String number_of_serving = intent.getStringExtra("number_of_serving");
        String recipe_category = intent.getStringExtra("recipe_category");
        String recipe_desc = intent.getStringExtra("recipe_desc");
        String preparation_time = intent.getStringExtra("preparation_time");
        String recipe_instructions = intent.getStringExtra("recipe_instructions");
        String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        String propellant = intent.getStringExtra("propellant");
        String imageURL = intent.getStringExtra("imageURL");
        String by = "by: ";
        String type = "recipe";

        tv_recipe_name.setText(name);
        tv_recipe_propellant.setText(by + propellant);
        tv_recipe_instructions.setText(recipe_instructions);
        Picasso.with(this).load(imageURL).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(iv);

    }


}
```

**select_ingredients.php**

```
    <?php 
require "conn.php";
$recipe_id = $_POST["recipe_id"]; 

$sql="select * from ingredients where recipe_id ='$recipe_id';";

$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if($result){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $flag[]=$row;
    }
    print(json_encode($flag));
}

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What did you try? You are showing no effort...

Comment: I tried many things that did not work. I just deleted the codes so that you sirs can understand. Sorry.

Comment: when you try many things, just post it, so we can know what did you try and what it is not required to test. Read your post from the forum side, and you will understand it.

Comment: ok sir. I'm sorry. Can you help me now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parse data with ?

just change

```
int recipe_id = 5 ; // for ex
    //SAVE/RETRIEVE URLS
    private static final String JSON_DATA_URL = "http://abcabc.com/select_ingredients.php?recipe_id="+recipe_id;
```

Update i forgot

change also

```
$_POST["recipe_id"]; to $_GET["recipe_id"];
```

Comment: thanks a lot sir. but do I still need to $_POST it in my php file? It's not working.

Comment: and if you wanna to send 2 parameter it will be the same idea but add & for ex select_ingredients.php?recipe_id="+recipe_id+"&"+"namehere="+namehere_data ........... $_GET["recipe_id"]  AND $_GET["namehere"]

Comment: i'm sorry i forget change $_POST["recipe_id"]; to $_GET["recipe_id"];

Comment: nvm do the last comment then told me

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you so much sir. I'm new to this and trying to understand everything by myself. Thankyou!

Comment: please help me again sir. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58951429/how-to-send-array-and-variable-from-php-to-android-studio