# How to send array and variable from php to android app?

Tags: php, android, arrays, android-alertdialog

I need help.
Have seen similar questions but I cant still do it. So I post mine.
php codes runs well so far. Ijust dont know how to get the array.
How can I get the array from php and list it in my alertdialog like this:

```
soy sauce - $1
onion - $1
total= $2
```

Or is this possible or not? Or maybe please tell me what to add in here. 
Thanks for your time in advance. Any form of help would be appreciated.

This are my codes:

```
public class updateData2 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postVars = new ArrayList<>();
        postVars.add(new BasicNameValuePair("JSON", String.valueOf(EverythingJSON)));
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://abcabc.com/buy_now.php");


        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postVars));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v("MAD", "Error sending... ");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v("MAD", "Error sending... ");
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(Cart.this,EverythingJSON.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Cart.this);
        builder.setTitle("ORDER:");
        builder.setMessage(EverythingJSON.toString());

        builder.setPositiveButton("Confirm",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                    {

                    }
                });

        builder.show();

    }


}
```

php

```
    <?php 
require "conn.php";
$total = 0;
// $ing = array("ampalaya", "soy sauce");
$JSON_Received = $_POST["JSON"];
$obj = json_decode($JSON_Received, true);

$products_name_array = array();
$products_price_array = array();

// foreach($ing as $value){

foreach($obj['ques'] as $value){

    $sql="select MIN(product_price) , product_id , store_id , product_name,product_unit_of_measure , product_price ,product_stock  from products where product_name like '%$value%'";

    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){

            $product_id=$row['product_id'];                           
            $store_id=$row['store_id'];                                 
            $product_name=$row['product_name'];                         $products_name_array[] = $product_name;
            $product_unit_of_measure=$row['product_unit_of_measure'];   
            $product_price=$row['product_price'];                       $products_price_array[] = $product_price;

            $total = $total+$product_price;

        }}

 }
foreach($products_name_array as $key => $value) {
    echo $products_name_array[$key] . " -    " . "$" . $products_price_array[$key] . ".00" ."<br>";
}


     echo "</br>";  
     echo "</br>";  
     echo "TOTAL IS:   ".$total. ".00"; 
     ?>
```

Comment: Add the response of your URL Call.

Comment: To android studio? To your android app i think.

Comment: @Rj_Innocent_Coder please atleast give me some hints to do it sir? I'm new at this. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Print result variable in onPostExecute Method and share the output

Comment: Anyone helpme?Please T.T

Answer (score 0):

example:
getArray.php

```
<? echo json_encode($your_array);?>
```

and in android use for example retrofit library(http client)

```
interface phpApi{
   @GET("url/getArray.php")
   Call<YourObject> getArray();
 }
```

Comment: not working sir. Please help me. I'm stuck on it for days.I know php but I'm a newbie in android.

Comment: Try use this example https://www.journaldev.com/13639/retrofit-android-example-tutorial